# How do I define a checkbox cell editor on a integer cell on JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I currently have a column in a JTable that stores integer values, and I've used the **setCellRenderer** function to either not show a checkbox and show it selected or not. Now I've figured out that I should override the **getCellEditor** function to be able to edit it, but can't figure it out.
Here's what I've done so far:

```
@Override
public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column) {
    if (column == 0){
        JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox();
        cb.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
                if(cb.isSelected()){
                    getModel().setValueAt(2, row, column);
                }else{
                    getModel().setValueAt(1, row, column);
                }
            }
        });
        return new DefaultCellEditor(cb);
    }else{
        return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't store integer values in the model. Store a Boolean value. It you need to use the value externally, then you convert the Boolean value to an appropriate integer value at that time.

Comment: *"How do I define a checkbox cell editor on a integer cell on JTable?"* Are the integers always either 0 or 1? If not, how does that even make sense? I would think if the value is true/false -> checkbox. If it's an integer, spinner with a number model. BTW: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I've made it clear, but I need this row to be integer because it stores values from 0 to 2, so I won't show the checkbox if it's 0, show it unselected if it's 1 and show selected if 2.

Comment: *so I won't show the checkbox if it's 0* - so how are you going to change the state to "selected" if you don't show the editor?

Comment: I don't need to change the state of the ones that are not showing.

Comment: So then the basic suggestion still stands. No need for a custom editor. Store a Boolean value to represent the 1/2 and null to represent the 0. Then you override the `isCellEditable(…)` method of the `JTable` to return false when the value is null. You would also have to override the `getColumnClass(…)` method to return `Boolean.class` for that column so the default editor can be used, when the cell is editable.

Comment: I'll try it out. Thank you!